# Firebaseから取得したデータをもとに地図上に複数のmarkerを表示したい

Tags: swift, ios, swift3, google-maps, firebase

コメントのような文章を投稿し、それを地図上に表示させる形式のSNSアプリを開発しています。
Googlemap APIとfirebaseのRealtime Databaseを利用しています。
現状、ログイン、投稿画面、地図の表示は済み、地図上にコンテンツを一つmarkerとして表示させるところまでは進みましたが、地図上に複数のコンテンツを表示させる方法がわからず困っております。
何卒ご教示頂ければ幸いです。

下記クラスでfirebase側から投稿データを取得しています
**PostData.swift**

```
class PostData: NSObject {
  var id: String?
  var userName: String?
  var text: String?
  var latitude: String?
  var longitude: String?

  init(snapshot: DataSnapshot, myId: String) {
    self.id = snapshot.key

    let valueDictionary = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]

    self.latitude = valueDictionary["latitude"] as? String
    self.longitude = valueDictionary["longitude"] as? String

    self.text = valueDictionary["text"] as? String

    self.userName = valueDictionary["userName"] as? String

  }
}
```

下記はメインの地図画面クラスです
**Map_ViewController.swift**

```
class Map_ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate{

  var mapManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
  var latitude: CLLocationDegrees!
  var longitude: CLLocationDegrees!
  var gmaps: GMSMapView!
  var postArray: [PostData] = []
  var observing = false
  var marker = GMSMarker()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapManager = CLLocationManager()
    latitude = CLLocationDegrees()
    longitude = CLLocationDegrees()

    mapManager.delegate = self
    mapManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    mapManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    mapManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    mapManager.distanceFilter = 1000
    mapManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    gmaps = GMSMapView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:self.view.bounds.width, height:self.view.bounds.width))
    self.view.addSubview(gmaps)
    gmaps.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    gmaps.settings.compassButton = true

    self.view = gmaps
    gmaps.delegate = self

    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
      if self.observing == false {

        let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child("messages")
        postsRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

          if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
            let postData = PostData(snapshot: snapshot, myId: uid)
            self.postArray.insert(postData, at: 0)
            print("\(self.postArray)")

            for element in self.postArray{
             self.makeMarker(postData: element)
            }

          }   
        })
      }
    }
  }

   func makeMarker(postData: PostData) -> GMSMarker {

      let latitude = Double(postData.latitude!)
      let longitude = Double(postData.longitude!)

      marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)

      marker.title = "\(postData.text!)"
      marker.tracksInfoWindowChanges = true //情報ウィンドウを自動的に更新するように設定する
      marker.appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation.pop //マーカーの表示にアニメーションをつける
      gmaps.selectedMarker = marker //デフォルトで情報ウィンドウを表示
      marker.map = self.gmaps
      return marker
      }

     //現在地の読み込み完了時に呼ばれるメソッド
     func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
      let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
      latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
      longitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude
      let now :GMSCameraPosition = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: latitude,longitude:longitude,zoom:14)
      gmaps.camera = now
    }
  }
```

ログを見るとfor文でアクセスしている配列postArray内にデータは引いてこれているので、その要素すべてにアクセスはできているとは思うのですが、makeMarkerメソッドがその要素ひとつぶんにしかアクセスできておらずmarkerが一つしか出せない状況です。(説明が悪くすみません)
forEach文に変えてみたりなどは試しましたが、結局1つしかmarkerを出せずといった感じです。

以上、アプローチの見直しも含めてご教示頂けますと幸いです。

Comment: `Map_ViewController`の中にはマーカーを表す変数は`marker`ひとつしかなく、`GMSMarker`のインスタンスも初期化式の中で1回しか作成されていないので、「markerが一つしか出せない」のは当たり前ですね。`makeMarker`では、名前と違い新しいマーカーは作らず、一つのマーカーの属性を何度も書き換えているだけです。`GMSMarker`の配列をもつプロパティを作る、`makeMarker`では呼ばれるたびに`GMSMarker`のインスタンスを作成し、先の配列に追加していく、と言った形で根本的な誤りは正せると思います。検証環境が作れないので、長文ですがコメントにて失礼します。

Comment: 本題ではありませんが、`CLLocationManager`は2回もインスタンスを作成していますね。どちらかは不要ですから削除した方が良いでしょう。不要なインスタンスの作成はメモリ管理上の負荷になる他、予期せぬ副作用を引き起こしたり、バグの要因になったりします。

Comment: 迅速なご回答誠にありがとうございます！大変勉強になります。ご教示頂いた方針でやってみます！

Comment: 解決できました！ありがとうございました！！

Comment: ご報告ありがとうございます。お時間をとって、回答をご自身で投稿(適切な時間を経たらさらに承認)していただけますでしょうか。FirebaseやGooble Mapはどちらも大変人気のあるサービスで、類似の事例で悩んでおられる多数の開発者に有用な情報となりうるかと思います。あなただけが動作確認されたコードにアクセスできるという状態です、是非ともよろしくお願いします。

Comment: 承知しました！もちろんです、気が回っておらず失礼いたしました。

Comment: 解決内容の追記ありがとうございます。ただ、申し訳ないのですが、このサイトでは、解決内容は自己解決の場合でも「回答」として投稿していただくことになっています。もう一手間かけて、解決内容の部分を「質問」から切り離して「回答」として投稿してくださるようお願いします。

Comment: なるほど、承知しました！勝手がわかっておらず失礼いたしました。重ねて御礼申し上げます！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

【解決しました！】
下記の通り変更したところ、複数markerを表示できるようになりました！
ご指導いただきました[OOPer](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/13972/ooper)さん、ありがとうございました！
　
**Map_ViewController.swift**

```
class Map_ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate{

  var mapManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
  var latitude: CLLocationDegrees! = CLLocationDegrees()
  var longitude: CLLocationDegrees! = CLLocationDegrees()
  var gmaps: GMSMapView!
  var postArray: [PostData] = []
  var markers: [GMSMarker] = []
  var observing = false

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapManager.delegate = self
    mapManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    mapManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    mapManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    mapManager.distanceFilter = 1000
    mapManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    gmaps = GMSMapView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:self.view.bounds.width, height:self.view.bounds.width))
    self.view.addSubview(gmaps)
    gmaps.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    gmaps.settings.compassButton = true

    self.view = gmaps
    gmaps.delegate = self

    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
      if self.observing == false {

        let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child("messages")
        postsRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

          if let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid {
            let postData = PostData(snapshot: snapshot, myId: uid)
            self.postArray.insert(postData, at: 0)
            self.makeMarker(postData: postData)
          }   
        })
      }
    }
  }

  func makeMarker(postData: PostData) -> [GMSMarker] {

      let marker = GMSMarker()
      let latitude = Double(postData.latitude!)
      let longitude = Double(postData.longitude!)

      marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)

      marker.title = "\(postData.text!)"
      marker.tracksInfoWindowChanges = true //情報ウィンドウを自動的に更新するように設定する
      marker.appearAnimation = GMSMarkerAnimation.pop //マーカーの表示にアニメーションをつける
      gmaps.selectedMarker = marker //デフォルトで情報ウィンドウを表示
      marker.map = self.gmaps

      markers = [marker]

      return markers
  }

     //現在地の読み込み完了時に呼ばれるメソッド
  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
    latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
    longitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude
    let now :GMSCameraPosition = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: latitude,longitude:longitude,zoom:14)
    gmaps.camera = now
  }
}
```

Comment: 回答の投稿ありがとうございました。問題を解決した回答(複数ある場合は最も役立った回答、もちろん今回の場合ご自身の回答)には「承認」の操作をお願いします。(多分グレーのチェックマークが表示されていると思います。)

Comment: 承知しました！質問から48時間後から操作できるようなので、時間を置いて押させていただきます！

Comment: ありがとうございます。今後も時に触れこのサイトをのぞいて見て、「質問」「回答」を問わずご経験を共有してくださることを願っております。それでは良いアプリを。

Comment: ありがとうございます！今回初めて質問させて頂いて、改めてとても素晴らしいプラットフォームだと実感しました。回答者としても貢献できるよう精進して参ります！
重ねて、本当にありがとうございました！